# Houses vs. Homes for a website name?

Tags: internet

I am opening a new website for a construction company, and I can’t decide between *www.x5houses.com* and *www.x5homes.com*. Which one is better?

Does *homes* sound better? If so, how much better and why?

Comment: Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers. See  Welcome to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange ---> http://english.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the 'how much better?' refinement is obviously POB, and the first question ('homes' sounds more user friendly ... more homely) is really seeking writing advice.

Comment: Guys, have a drink. *"Most appropriate name"* for a *"given type of company"* questions are common on here.  And, it's a fascinating question for any linguist.  "Advertising language" is (tragically) a big part of "language" today - more so in English than any other. You two jokers are UK based right?  Just recuse yourselves and go have a gin and tonic   :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

FWIW, I'd go with "homes".  I assume this is in the USA.  It does depend somewhat on the region but, quite simply, if you look in the phone book, **that is the more usual choice, these days, for that type of company.**

Hopefully, someone will bother to add some references to this - I can't be bothered.

---

To be clear, do they **buy empty lots, run the finance, build a house, and then sell it to the owner**?  If so, stick with "homes."

(If they are "literally" a builder, which is less and less common these days, I'd go with Smith Family Building or similar, something with "building" or "builders".)

Indeed, for a more precise answer you'd have to explain more clearly what they do.